# How to use Bitbucket api in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rest, bitbucket

Which is the best way to use bitbucket api in ruby on rails. Is there any gem available to handle bitbucket ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no specific gem available.

But by re-mapping your repo to bitbucket you can use bitbucket in rails seamlessly.

Assuming you were previously in github...

```
   git remote set-url [example] [git://github.com/user/test.git]
```

where [example] = repo name

```
   [git://github.com/user/test.git] = new repo url
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most popular gem for Bitbucket api https://github.com/bitbucket-rest-api/bitbucket

Answer (score 0):

As per my findings there is no updated gem for integrating Bitbucket APIs in rails application.

You can simply follow this updated **bitbucket REST documentation** to integrate APIs:
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/intro/

PS: I know this questions is past now, still posting answer here because I went through the same issue.
So maybe it will help to resolve.